# biblatex sort by year and name both descending

Tags: biblatex

I sort bibliography using `sorting=ydnt`. This option sorts entries first by year descending, and by name (ascending), and then title (ascending).

Is there a way to change name ascending to name descending sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new sorting template `ydndt` based on `ydnt` where you just add a `[direction=descending]` to the name sorting block.

```
\DeclareSortingTemplate{ydndt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}
```